# Spring Batch question for email summary at the end of all jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have approximately 20 different Spring Batch jobs (some running as microservices, some lumped together in one Spring Boot app). What I need to do is gather all the errors encountered by ALL the jobs, as well as the number of records processed, and summarize it all in an email.

I have implemented `ItemListenerSupport` as a start:

```
public class BatchItemListener extends ItemListenerSupport<BaseDomainDataObject, BaseDomainDataObject> {
    private final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(BatchItemListener.class);
    private final static Map<String, Integer> numProcessedMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final static Map<String, Integer> errorMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void onReadError(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Encountered error on read", ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessError(BaseDomainDataObject item, Exception ex) {
        String msgBody = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
        errorMap.put(item, msgBody);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWriteError(Exception ex, List<? extends BaseDomainDataObject> items) {
        logger.error("Encountered error on write", ex);
        numProcessedMap.computeIfAbsent("numErrors", val -> items.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterWrite(List<? extends BaseDomainDataObject> items) {
        logger.info("Logging successful number of items written...");
        numProcessedMap.computeIfAbsent("numSuccess", val -> items.size());
    }
}
```

But how to I access the errors I accumulate in the listener when my batch jobs are finally finished? Right now I don't even have a good way to know when they are all finished. Any suggestions? Does Spring Batch provide something better for summarizing jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Batch does not provide a way to orchestrate jobs. The closest you can get out of the box is using a "master" job with multiple steps of type [Jobstep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) that delegate to your sub-jobs. with this approach, you can do the aggregation in a `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` configured on the master job.

Otherwise, you can [Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://dataflow.spring.io) and create a [composed task](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/batch/data-flow-composed-task/) of all your jobs.